# WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0: Getting Error as "Message : Invalid callback URL found in the request." during signup/Register Now

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When i try to register a user using *Register Now* option from SIGN-IN screen, after entering all user info and on click REGESTER, getting error

> Message : Invalid callback URL found in the request.

There are no errors in wso2carbon.log.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7946

Comment: Fix for this - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2592/files